# Is it possible to read System.Windows.Forms.Design.DesignerOptions.GridSize at runtime?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is it possible to read `System.Windows.Forms.Design.DesignerOptions.GridSize` at runtime?

I'm doing some dynamic control positioning, and I'd like to move them at intervals of GridSize. I understand it's a design-related value, so I'm not sure if it can be read at runtime, or how to do it.

I could simply do something like...

```
Private Const gdsz As Integer = 16
```

...in the form code, but I'd rather have it read GridSize directly from the form design settings.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.design.windowsformsdesigneroptionservice.compatibilityoptions?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: What is stopping you just referencing that value directly, with an assembly reference to `System.Windows.Forms.Design.dll`? Note that the settings you use in Visual Studio are not accessible from your compiled app.

Comment: Ahh I was wondering about accessibility in the compiled app (among other issues). After fiddling with Hans' comment above last night, I was able to determine it wouldn't work anyways. The values I was getting were incorrect. They appeared to be defaults rather than the actual design values for the form. So I will have to go back to my original solution of a `Const` value.

Comment: What's wrong with simply using the standard Anchor, docking, Table/Flow layout panels?  Just saying because in my experience when trying to force dynamic UI layouts, things can get really messy and complicated fast leaving the end user with a sometime rather average experience

Comment: @hursey yes I've already put some controls in Table Layout Panels. I had already done so before, but now I'm adding more. And yes it can get messy but I'm being meticulous about it. So far, so good.